# Pipeline apt-get update Fails

Tags: bitbucket, pipeline, apt-get, bitbucket-pipelines

I get this error when running my pipeline file here is my pipeline file: I am a front-end Dev this is the first time build/creating a automative process like this any pointer on how to get it to work or improvement would be appreciated.

```
# This is a sample build configuration for JavaScript.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/14UWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: node:10.9.0
pipelines: 
branches: 
master: 
- step: max-time: 10 
name: production 
deployment: production 
caches: 
- node 
script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository. 
- npm install 
- npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.3 
- ng build --prod 
- apt-get clean 
- apt-get update 
- apt-get install ncftp 
- ncftpput -v -u $FTP_USERNAME -p $FTP_PASSWORD -R $FTP_HOST $FTP_SITE_ROOT dist/* 
- echo Finished uploading files to $FTP_HOST$FTP_SITE_R
definitions: caches: ncftp: /var/cache/apt node: node_modules
```

here is my error:

```
+ apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [7340 B]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2420 B]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [825 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
Fetched 10.1 MB in 8s (1182 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am not sure how to get apt-get to work in Bitbucket this pipeline file was working fine a couple of weeks ago.  Any thoughts no what I can do to get it working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node images should default to debian stretch instead of jessie now. Bitbucket may be caching the old image. You can force the stretch version by setting the image to `node:<version>-stretch`

Related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/1013

Comment: Thanks @Oscar Barrett that looks to have solved my issue.